# How to retrieve Plist data from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, info.plist

Hi i am new to the iPhone.

I have stored some data in Plist file. Once I tap the upload button in application all the data to be posted in web service.

In my code I wrote, **instead of posting all the data I wrongly posted last data alone**. Also my project went to production. Client tried to post the data but last data only has updated in web service.

Now I solved that issue. If I tap upload button all the data will be posted in web service and I am going to release the build for production, but **can I retrieve plist data from earlier production build which are data not posted in web service.**

Comment: are you want to get the data into the .plist file

Comment: Not necessary to get the data in .plist file. all the data are users signature image. i need that signature images

Comment: I just downloaded [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/?utm_expid=15979170-15&utm_referrer=https://www.google.co.in/) by using this we can browse our iOS device data. Finally i got the plist file through this software.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update anything that's part of the bundle. Save the plist in the documents directory if you want to be able to update it.

```
NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Files in the documents directory don't get deleted when updating an app using the store.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i saved the plist file in documents directory only.now i am going to send the new build to client. can i get the older build plist data. i did not use app store

Comment: try to append the plist file and not overwrite it. I think you should be able to retrieve data from it.

Comment: Pls help me out. how to append the plist file

Comment: i tried below steps but plist does not have any data but if run the build in device i could read the data.                         First, unzip the .ipa file(which is sent by client to us after storing the data in plist). (we can rename it with .zip to do this). Then, inside the .ipa file, we will find there is a Info.plist file. in that plist file i could not see any data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % that I understand your question. I have plist in my project that I use for layout information. These plists are already included in my app.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MapLayout" ofType:@"plist"];
NSURL *markerDataURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSDictionary *data = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:markerDataURL];
NSArray *array = [data allKeys];
```

This puts all the data into a dictionary, but what you do next depends on what is in your plist in the first place.